# "Commands out of sync" in MySQL database dump if triggers are included

Tags: mysql, trigger, mariadb

I'm attempting to copy a database including triggers.

I already have a working data & structure dump - so I made a dump of the triggers using:

`mysqldump --routines --no-create-info --no-data --no-create-db --skip-opt > triggers.sql`

When I execute it, it creates the first trigger, then halts with "commands out of sync" at the second call to

```
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = @saved_sql_mode */ ;
```

Removing that line just makes it halt at the next, and so on.

Any ideas how I can copy the triggers without having to do them one at a time?

Sample of the generated dump:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.14  Distrib 5.5.49-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: <something>
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.5.49-MariaDB-1ubuntu0.14.04.1
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_client      = @@character_set_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_results     = @@character_set_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_col_connection = @@collation_connection */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = utf8_general_ci */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_sql_mode       = @@sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = '' */ ;
DELIMITER ;;
DROP TRIGGER if exists attendance_bulk_mark_audit;;
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`master`@`%`*/ /*!50003 TRIGGER `attendance_bulk_mark_audit` AFTER UPDATE ON `attendance_bulk_mark` FOR EACH ROW
        INSERT INTO `attendance_bulk_mark_audit_log` SET
        attendance_bulk_mark_id = OLD.id,
        start_date = OLD.start_date,
        mark = OLD.mark,
        core_user_id = OLD.core_user_id,
        created = OLD.created,
        updated = OLD.updated,
        end_date = OLD.end_date,
        classes = OLD.classes,
        tutor_groups = OLD.tutor_groups,
        courses = OLD.courses,
        levels = OLD.levels,
        everyone = OLD.everyone; */;;
DELIMITER ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = @saved_sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = @saved_cs_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = @saved_cs_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = @saved_col_connection */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_client      = @@character_set_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_results     = @@character_set_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_col_connection = @@collation_connection */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = utf8_general_ci */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_sql_mode       = @@sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = '' */ ;
DELIMITER ;;
DROP TRIGGER if exists attendance_mark_audit;;
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`master`@`%`*/ /*!50003 TRIGGER `attendance_mark_audit` AFTER UPDATE ON `attendance_mark` FOR EACH ROW
        INSERT INTO `attendance_mark_audit_log` SET
        attendance_mark_id = OLD.id,
        student_core_user_id = OLD.student_core_user_id,
        staff_core_user_id = OLD.staff_core_user_id,
        mark = OLD.mark,
        minutes_late = OLD.minutes_late,
        core_class_timetable_id = OLD.core_class_timetable_id,
        core_class_id = OLD.core_class_id,
        core_module_id = OLD.core_module_id,
        core_tutor_group_id = OLD.core_tutor_group_id,
        created = OLD.created,
        updated = OLD.updated,
        register_id = OLD.register_id,
        register_date = OLD.register_date,
        period = OLD.period,
        student_register_id = OLD.student_register_id */;;
DELIMITER ;
```

**EDIT** After a suggestion by @dbdemon, I removed all the SET lines, so now it looks like

```
-- MySQL dump 10.14  Distrib 5.5.49-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: <something>
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.5.49-MariaDB-1ubuntu0.14.04.1

DELIMITER ;;
DROP TRIGGER if exists attendance_bulk_mark_audit;;
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`master`@`%`*/ /*!50003 TRIGGER `attendance_bulk_mark_audit` AFTER UPDATE ON `attendance_bulk_mark` FOR EACH ROW
        INSERT INTO `attendance_bulk_mark_audit_log` SET
        attendance_bulk_mark_id = OLD.id,
        start_date = OLD.start_date,
        mark = OLD.mark,
        core_user_id = OLD.core_user_id,
        created = OLD.created,
        updated = OLD.updated,
        end_date = OLD.end_date,
        classes = OLD.classes,
        tutor_groups = OLD.tutor_groups,
        courses = OLD.courses,
        levels = OLD.levels,
        everyone = OLD.everyone; */;;
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER ;;
DROP TRIGGER if exists attendance_mark_audit;;
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`master`@`%`*/ /*!50003 TRIGGER `attendance_mark_audit` AFTER UPDATE ON `attendance_mark` FOR EACH ROW
        INSERT INTO `attendance_mark_audit_log` SET
        attendance_mark_id = OLD.id,
        student_core_user_id = OLD.student_core_user_id,
        staff_core_user_id = OLD.staff_core_user_id,
        mark = OLD.mark,
        minutes_late = OLD.minutes_late,
        core_class_timetable_id = OLD.core_class_timetable_id,
        core_class_id = OLD.core_class_id,
        core_module_id = OLD.core_module_id,
        core_tutor_group_id = OLD.core_tutor_group_id,
        created = OLD.created,
        updated = OLD.updated,
        register_id = OLD.register_id,
        register_date = OLD.register_date,
        period = OLD.period,
        student_register_id = OLD.student_register_id */;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Still it fails at the next command after the first trigger, with:

```
DROP TRIGGER if exists attendance_mark_audit - Error Code: 2014. Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

I also tried moving the `DROP TRIGGER if exists attendance_mark_audit;;` to before the `DELIMITER;;` (removing the extra semicolon) but it still had the same result.

Comment: The "Commands out of sync" error can be a result of tables having errors and having crashed. Run `CHECK TABLE attendance_bulk_mark;` to see if this could be the case. If so, `REPAIR TABLE attendance_bulk_mark;` can fix the problem. Also, I'm not sure if this would be relevant, but have you checked to see if there are errors in the triggers? BTW, you appear to be dumping from a MariaDB database version 5.5, but what version of MariaDB / MySQL are you importing it into?

Comment: Ah thanks dbdemon - there's a version difference - the target is 5.7. Check table found no problems btw. But version differences might account for it. I'm not really in a position to test that theory at the moment though.

Pending anyone else giving me a "proven" answer, please add this as an answer and I'll accept as it seems like a logical cause.

Comment: I would have thought importing from MariaDB 5.5 into MySQL 5.7 should be OK, actually. As a potential workaround, how about just stripping out all the lines starting with `/*!50003 SET`? I don't think these lines are strictly needed for creating these triggers, so it might be worth a try.

Comment: Thanks @dbdemon - no joy. Answer updated to reflect what I tried.

Comment: I'm curious if the problem is related to the particular command `DROP TRIGGER if exists attendance_mark_audit` or if you get the error on the second `DROP ...` regardless of which one you've put in second place.   Have you tried changing the order of the `DROP TRIGGER ...` commands? Also, as a potential workaround, presumably the target database is empty when you start copying, so you can probably just remove the `DROP TRIGGER` statements from the SQL file.

Comment: I added the `drop trigger`, because the first time I ran it, it made the first trigger, then failed at the second command. So, no, it's not related to the `drop trigger`. It's basically *any* sql after creating the trigger from what I can tell. Before removing the `/*!5003 SET` lines, it was failing on those.

Comment: OK. I just created a similar trigger (in MariaDB) and used your syntax from attendance_bulk_mark_audit, but am actually getting an error because of the semi-colon just before the end of the "comment". Removing this semi-colon makes it work. You don't have a semi-colon like this in the next trigger, attendance_mark_audit. So maybe try removing it?

Comment: Yes - that did it - thanks again for sticking with it, @dbdemon - the error message was completely misleading me.